# force a program to use discrete gpu with opengl support

Tags: nvidia, wayland, opengl

Currently on wayland with an nvidia dGPU

I generally would like to leave the gpu mode to hybrid mode to save power and occasionally run a program using the dGPU specifically. This program requires openGL support.

Is there a command I can type to start a program using the dGPU?

Apparently in windows, you can right click on desktop shortcut and "run with high performance GPU".

Wondering if this is also possible with wayland-nvidia.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334825/what-are-the-steps-to-run-wayland-on-21-04-with-optimus-nvidia

Comment: thanks I figured it out. Installed nvidia-prime. Then ran prime-run

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov IMO you should create the anwser from orginal ubuntu post with some context

Comment: @AlexBaranowski I create answers only when I can test them, and since I don't have an optimus laptop anywhere near me, I'll pass. Reposting something is not my forte.

Answer (score 0):

I found this working in Fedora. When running the program:

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia <app_name>
```

[Source](https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/Optimus#Configure_Graphics_Applications_to_Render_Using_the_GPU_Screen). See the "Finer-Grained Control of GLX + OpenGL" section.